# dotnet test on MacOS M1 logs 'Invalid platform type: anycpu'

Tags: .net-core, apple-m1

Here's a sample csproj file for one of my unit tests:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>

    <Platforms>AnyCPU;x64</Platforms>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

When I run `dotnet test` on my solution on MacOS with Apple silicon, I find this on the console:

```
Invalid platform type: anycpu. Valid platform types are X86, X64, ARM, ARM64, S390x.
```

How can I properly fix it to run on my machine as well as the other team members who are using Windows and Linux?